# Trouble in grouping the values from excel?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a excel file which is as follows .

```
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       02/04/2012  10:30:39    20:23:14
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       03/04/2012  09:46:01    19:58:16
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       04/04/2012  10:06:26    19:58:31
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       05/04/2012  11:38:51    19:32:17
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       06/04/2012  10:43:06    21:02:06
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       09/04/2012  11:02:32    22:05:14
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       10/04/2012  10:49:41    19:07:48
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       11/04/2012  10:16:42    20:30:13
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       12/04/2012  10:15:54    19:54:51
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       13/04/2012  10:18:30    19:05:55
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       18/04/2012  10:52:37    18:50:36
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       19/04/2012  10:24:59    20:29:59
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       20/04/2012  10:29:47    18:58:23
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       23/04/2012  10:24:31    20:11:29
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       24/04/2012  10:13:18    19:05:25
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       25/04/2012  10:44:53    16:30:13
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       26/04/2012  10:44:01    19:25:51
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       27/04/2012  10:58:37    19:24:37
1   Kr Veerappan    123 Hardware Team       30/04/2012  11:16:04    22:34:21
12310452    Ravi Pandit 123 Contractor      02/04/2012  10:59:52    20:10:36
12310452    Ravi Pandit 123 Contractor      03/04/2012  11:12:25    20:44:23
   115  Narayana Rao    123 Client Application Team     21/04/2012  15:59:41    16:52:10
115 Narayana Rao    123 Client Application Team     22/04/2012  10:35:03    12:24:54
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     03/04/2012  10:16:02    19:19:50
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     04/04/2012  10:15:47    20:44:08
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     05/04/2012  11:03:18    18:48:46
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     06/04/2012  10:54:41    18:26:38
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     09/04/2012  11:34:15    19:31:29
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     10/04/2012  12:15:34    21:14:02
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     11/04/2012  09:29:16    20:11:02
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     12/04/2012  12:08:09    20:17:53
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     13/04/2012  11:42:39    20:04:53
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     14/04/2012  11:08:13    19:05:49
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     16/04/2012  11:29:49    18:42:21
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     17/04/2012  14:13:40    19:09:58
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     18/04/2012  10:43:03    19:50:01
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     19/04/2012  11:07:09    18:29:44
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     21/04/2012  10:07:04    18:08:43
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     23/04/2012  11:28:05    19:46:04
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     24/04/2012  11:46:01    19:36:22
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     25/04/2012  10:59:08    19:56:39
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     26/04/2012  11:56:34    20:22:05
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     27/04/2012  11:41:21    19:43:51
117 Butchi B Paddi  123 Mobile Team     30/04/2012  11:58:35    20:21:36
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     02/04/2012  10:33:08    14:51:02
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     05/04/2012  10:29:07    19:37:37
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     06/04/2012  10:43:06    15:20:56
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     10/04/2012  09:54:19    18:42:37
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     11/04/2012  09:59:44    18:38:20
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     12/04/2012  10:53:42    18:48:43
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     13/04/2012  10:19:11    19:32:57
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     24/04/2012  09:38:58    19:46:15
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     25/04/2012  09:41:14    19:38:27
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     26/04/2012  10:15:53    20:08:55
119 Sarish Nayak    001 Mobile Team     27/04/2012  09:59:06    19:06:02
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       02/04/2012  10:19:44    21:45:20
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       03/04/2012  10:36:08    20:48:28
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       04/04/2012  10:18:37    22:54:23
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       05/04/2012  10:29:14    22:45:08
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       06/04/2012  10:46:33    21:04:38
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       09/04/2012  10:30:50    20:48:48
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       10/04/2012  10:20:36    20:22:51
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       11/04/2012  10:57:13    22:29:50
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       12/04/2012  10:27:47    21:43:52
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       13/04/2012  10:23:33    21:51:19
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       16/04/2012  10:43:52    20:08:14
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       17/04/2012  10:21:48    23:34:04
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       18/04/2012  10:29:54    18:24:57
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       19/04/2012  10:32:54    22:34:13
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       23/04/2012  10:31:01    21:54:44
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       24/04/2012  10:44:52    23:30:50
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       25/04/2012  02:19:51    21:03:21
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       26/04/2012  10:36:07    22:52:40
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       27/04/2012  10:40:58    21:41:16
120 Manjunatha Dn   065 Hardware Team       30/04/2012  10:43:33    22:32:15
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     02/04/2012  11:18:11    20:18:34
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     03/04/2012  11:00:37    19:05:52
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     04/04/2012  10:49:30    20:24:35
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     05/04/2012  10:20:59    19:53:49
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     06/04/2012  11:15:03    18:17:20
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     09/04/2012  11:21:01    19:36:11
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     10/04/2012  10:38:39    20:40:26
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     11/04/2012  10:07:13    19:16:23
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     12/04/2012  10:39:32    17:33:30
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     13/04/2012  10:49:31    19:33:58
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     16/04/2012  12:13:08    20:13:14
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     17/04/2012  10:45:31    20:27:33
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     18/04/2012  13:17:38    19:46:26
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     19/04/2012  11:13:41    19:17:13
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     23/04/2012  10:54:53    19:13:41
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     24/04/2012  10:26:54    19:31:41
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     25/04/2012  12:30:13    18:56:19
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     26/04/2012  11:19:46    20:42:33
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     27/04/2012  11:38:42    17:23:34
121 Ashwini Amol Kulkarni   123 Qa Team     30/04/2012  16:09:55    20:04:45
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     02/04/2012  11:12:52    20:51:39
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     03/04/2012  10:51:50    21:05:26
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     04/04/2012  11:27:50    19:03:20
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     09/04/2012  12:00:08    19:40:01
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     10/04/2012  11:57:59    20:14:18
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     11/04/2012  10:55:41    18:43:04
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     12/04/2012  13:37:39    19:02:58
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     13/04/2012  10:47:50    18:34:46
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     16/04/2012  11:05:04    19:59:02
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     17/04/2012  10:57:45    19:34:32
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     18/04/2012  11:15:32    19:23:40
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     19/04/2012  12:42:23    19:05:18
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     23/04/2012  11:16:11    19:14:55
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     24/04/2012  11:05:07    18:44:45
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     26/04/2012  11:28:21    18:30:26
122 Melvin P Perinchery 073 Mobile Team     27/04/2012  11:35:13    18:53:09
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     02/04/2012  10:55:53    20:22:10
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     03/04/2012  10:52:14    19:12:11
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     04/04/2012  11:19:28    22:26:03
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     05/04/2012  10:08:21    20:14:40
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     06/04/2012  10:46:01    15:04:14
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     09/04/2012  10:47:02    18:42:00
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     10/04/2012  11:36:47    19:35:51
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     11/04/2012  11:06:07    20:24:37
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     12/04/2012  10:30:28    19:47:31
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     13/04/2012  10:38:22    20:47:39
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     16/04/2012  11:25:59    19:44:00
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     17/04/2012  11:43:50    19:54:12
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     18/04/2012  10:12:31    19:56:19
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     19/04/2012  10:50:11    20:20:50
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     21/04/2012  12:09:09    18:30:17
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     23/04/2012  10:46:34    18:33:16
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     24/04/2012  10:57:27    19:43:56
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     25/04/2012  10:35:21    19:00:49
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     26/04/2012  11:22:14    19:23:42
123 Srinivas R Kaka 065 Qa Team     27/04/2012  10:58:41    14:39:33
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        02/04/2012  10:32:21    19:04:40
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        03/04/2012  10:19:37    19:44:45
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        04/04/2012  10:20:22    19:14:41
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        05/04/2012  09:55:52    19:49:13
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        06/04/2012  09:41:59    19:48:23
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        09/04/2012  10:09:36    19:47:30
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        10/04/2012  10:05:47    19:46:35
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        11/04/2012  10:08:27    20:54:45
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        12/04/2012  10:17:44    20:07:29
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        13/04/2012  10:00:08    20:16:36
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        16/04/2012  10:02:32    19:53:39
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        17/04/2012  09:57:33    21:47:45
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        18/04/2012  10:21:35    18:54:46
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        19/04/2012  09:55:52    22:24:15
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        23/04/2012  09:53:19    19:10:49
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        24/04/2012  09:47:38    19:51:01
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        25/04/2012  10:27:02    19:20:06
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        26/04/2012  10:19:55    19:42:20
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        27/04/2012  09:57:48    19:44:49
12310637    Manikantha  123 System Admin        30/04/2012  09:53:48    20:30:34
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      02/04/2012  09:59:55    20:46:42
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      03/04/2012  10:37:15    21:56:23
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      04/04/2012  10:31:51    19:36:49
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      05/04/2012  11:20:40    20:11:41
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      06/04/2012  10:19:19    21:18:34
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      09/04/2012  10:49:12    19:52:51
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      10/04/2012  10:40:18    20:32:47
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      11/04/2012  10:05:50    20:23:45
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      12/04/2012  10:56:13    19:55:19
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      13/04/2012  10:29:22    20:14:39
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      16/04/2012  10:48:22    20:32:47
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      18/04/2012  09:52:18    21:44:43
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      19/04/2012  10:35:28    19:28:30
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      23/04/2012  10:32:22    19:09:25
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      24/04/2012  11:24:52    19:35:56
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      25/04/2012  11:00:23    19:35:40
12310647    Plain Card  123 Temporary Card      26/04/2012  10:59:39    21:04:15
```

I am trying to group these values in to a map like following :

```
private static Map showExcelData(List sheetData) {
        String tempEmpid="",strdepartment="";
        int j=1;

        Map employeeMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        Map tempEmployeeMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
                HSSFCell employeeid = (HSSFCell) list.get(0);
                HSSFCell department = (HSSFCell) list.get(3);
                HSSFCell date = (HSSFCell) list.get(5);

                strdepartment = department.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                      if(!(employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("EmpID") || date.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("Date") || department.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("Department"))){

                           if(!(strdepartment.equals("Temporary Card") || strdepartment.equals("Contractor"))){
                                   employeeMap.put(employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString()+"_"+j,date.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                                   j++;   
                            }
                       }// System.out.println("");
        }
        return employeeMap;
    }
```

i think here itself i can group the values based on employee id but to be very frank i don't know how to do this since i am new quy in java.

so i try to get the map from the above method and try to process as follows

```
employeeMap =  showExcelData(sheetData);
        String previousEemployeeID = "",employeeID[];
        Iterator<Map.Entry> entries = employeeMap.entrySet().iterator();
        int i=0;
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = entries.next();
            employeeID = entry.getKey().toString().split("_");
            System.out.println("employeeid : "+employeeID[0]);

            if(previousEemployeeID.equals(employeeID[0])){
                System.out.println(" If Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()+"  : possible key is : "+employeeID[0]+"_"+String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
            }else{
                if(i==0) System.out.println("previousEmployee id : "+entry.getKey()); 
                System.out.println("Else Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()+"  : possible key is : "+employeeID[0]+"_"+String.valueOf(i));
                i=0;
            }
            previousEemployeeID = employeeID[0];

        }
```

Here i just want to group the values based on employee id but really getting bad answer, if i try as it was above first element from map is getting eliminated and the from second element it is coming fine.

here is the full code :

```
package org.slingemp.attendance;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReadEmployeeAttendanceDesktop {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map employeeMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        String fileName = "D:/workspace/FinalFileUpload/SampleData.xls";

        // Create an ArrayList to store the data read from excel sheet.
        List sheetData = new ArrayList();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {

            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

            // Create an excel workbook from the file system.
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);// gets the first sheet on workbook

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                //count=count+1;
                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    data.add(cell);
                }

                sheetData.add(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        employeeMap =  showExcelData(sheetData);
        String previousEemployeeID = "",employeeID[];
        Iterator<Map.Entry> entries = employeeMap.entrySet().iterator();
        int i=0;
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = entries.next();
            employeeID = entry.getKey().toString().split("_");
            System.out.println("employeeid : "+employeeID[0]);

            if(previousEemployeeID.equals(employeeID[0])){
                System.out.println(" If Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()+"  : possible key is : "+employeeID[0]+"_"+String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
            }else{
                if(i==0) System.out.println("previousEmployee id : "+entry.getKey()); 
                System.out.println("Else Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()+"  : possible key is : "+employeeID[0]+"_"+String.valueOf(i));
                i=0;
            }
            previousEemployeeID = employeeID[0];

        }
    }
    private static Map showExcelData(List sheetData) {
        String tempEmpid="",strdepartment="";
        int j=1;

        Map employeeMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        Map tempEmployeeMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
                HSSFCell employeeid = (HSSFCell) list.get(0);
                HSSFCell department = (HSSFCell) list.get(3);
                HSSFCell date = (HSSFCell) list.get(5);

                strdepartment = department.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                      if(!(employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("EmpID") || date.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("Date") || department.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("Department"))){

                           if(!(strdepartment.equals("Temporary Card") || strdepartment.equals("Contractor"))){
                                   employeeMap.put(employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString()+"_"+j,date.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                                   j++;   
                            }
                       }// System.out.println("");
        }
        return employeeMap;
    }
}
```

so please help me to the following :

1. group the values based on employees id.

thanks in advance
Anthony Raj S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the following,

```
1.Put the values based on employeeid
2.put the employee id in a separeate arraylist
3.Iterate both map and Arraylist
4.and put the values as follows in the map
Map<String,Map<String,String>> where first one employee id and other dates
```

Hope this will help you.